# What are the chances I get a ticket?

Tags: parking

I'm visiting CT from out of state. I had to run into a store for literally two minutes. The parking lot was full ans the only open spots were four handicap spots. My brother was in the car so I pulled into one of the handicap spots and told him to move the car if a spots opens up, but that I'd be back in a min.

A woman follows me into the store and says she's calling the police. I said ok, did what I needed to do and left. As I was leaving she was calling the police and said she took a photo of my car.

What are the chances that I receive a ticket?  Was a dumb move and I never do it, but was in a rush.

Comment: This isn't a legal question, unless you're asking whether the photo of you parked illegally is admissible in court.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a legal question - the chance of being detected for breaking the law is not about the law.

Comment: He's already been detected. It's a question about how the law is likely to be applied, i.e., a question about the law.

Answer (score 3):

Close to zero. The police typically don't dole out traffic or parking tickets for infractions they haven't personally witnessed.

Comment: Do you have a reason to think that the photographic evidence would be inadmissible?

Comment: Assuming she showed up for a trial, I'd imagine it would be authenticated and admitted. But I wouldn't assume she'd show up for trial.